# Posting a variable to a PHP File with Ajax to delete a row from Mysql - doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

here's my Ajax function.:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
  $("#deletebutton").click(function(){
    var del_id  = $(this).attr('name');
    var answer = confirm ("Are you sure?");
    if (answer)

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "deletescript.php",
           data:'delete_id='+del_id,
                success: function(data)
                {
                   alert("Done!");
                }
           });
   });
});
```

And here's the affected button:

```
echo'<input type="button" name="'.$id.'" id="deletebutton" value="delete">'
```

Here's my PHP Script called **deletescript.php**:

```
$id = $_POST['delete_id'];
$query = "DELETE from items where id = '$id'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

Even when I get "Done!" as an alert - my Item still exists. I also checked with Firebug that the correct ID is succesfully sent to the deletescript.php file. What do I have to do? I also tested the SQL-Query manually on my Databse and it worked. Searched for similar questions and found some, sadly even their solutions didn't help. I don't know what to do...
Thank you!

Comment: rather than alert('Done') check for alert(data) see what it returns

Comment: Do you have more than one button with `id="deletebutton"`?

Comment: @joyBlanks Since `deletescript.php` doesn't echo anything, there won't be anything in `data`.

Comment: @Barmar No. It's a unique id.

Comment: `alert(del_id);` check if you are getting the id.

Comment: Try with `data:{delete_id : del_id};` and `$query = "DELETE from items where id = ".$id;`

Comment: @Shehary Yes, I get the correct ID.

Comment: Add error checking to the PHP script. Use Firebug to see if there are any error messages in the response.

Comment: it may sound stupid but in `deletescript.php` database is called or file include?

Comment: @Hackerman Still doesn't work.. :/

Comment: Try an `echo $result` in your PHP + alert(data)

Comment: @Shehary Yes. Database is included. It's the same file I use everywhere. So the conenction is working.

Comment: Try one hardcoded id in your php script and see if is deleted from the items table(execute the script directly)

Comment: @joyBlanks It's still empty. I think we are getting closer.

Comment: ok I can see you didnt add a `.error : function(){}` callback can you add that and check the error code if any

Comment: I'm assuming you have made a DB connection it is just not in you code that is showing?

Answer (score 0):

Let print your full query and execute this in your database management tool. So you can see exactly which query it is.

Generally, I will say a couple of things to you:

- For deletion, send a DELETE request instead of POST
- Don't put variables between quotes
- Sanatize query parameters to prevent sql injection

Better alternative and solution for you:

*Soft deleting*

- Add state field to your table
- You can have active state and non active state (deleted)
- Do you want to delete record? Set state to non active
- Default read out the active items

Answer (score 0):

try jquery $.post:

```
    $( document ).ready(function(){
  $("#deletebutton").click(function(){
    var del_id  = parseInt($(this).attr('name'));
    var answer = confirm ("Are you sure?");
    if (answer){

        $.post('deletescript.php',{id:del_id}, function(callback){
            if(callback){
                alert("Done!");
            }
        });

    }
   });
});
```

The PHP file will get access to the id with $_POST['id']
The callback will contain whatever ur PHP file will echo/show

Comment: Doesn't work either... the ajax posting works fine - I think the problem might be in deletescript.php... or so